# How to store synonyms as column in data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

Want to store Getting result of below code in data frame.

Two columns one is the actual name and another is each synonym in the new row.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
import pandas as pd

List = ['protest','riot','conflict']
df=[]
def process_genre(str):
    for genre in str:
        result = []
        for syn in wordnet.synsets(genre):
            for l in syn.lemmas():
                result.append(l.name())
        print(set(result))
process_genre(List)

output:
-------
{'resist', 'objection', 'dissent', 'protestation', 'protest'}
{'bacchanalia', 'riot', 'saturnalia', 'belly_laugh', 'scream', 'wow', 'bacchanal', 'thigh-slapper', 'sidesplitter', 'drunken_revelry', 'carouse', 'rioting', 'roister', 'debauchery', 'orgy', 'public_violence', 'howler', 'debauch'}
{'fight', 'battle', 'difference', 'dispute', 'conflict', 'infringe', 'engagement', 'struggle', 'difference_of_opinion', 'contravene', 'run_afoul'}
```

Want to store the result in data frame:

```
# Expected Result:

Col1           Col2
--------------------
protest       resist
protest       objection
protest       dissent
...           ...
riot          scream
riot          carouse
riot          saturnalia
...           ...
conflict      Fight
conflict      battle
...           ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
import pandas as pd

def process_genres(genres):
    return (pd.DataFrame([(genre, l.name())
                          for genre in genres
                          for syn in wordnet.synsets(genre)
                          for l in syn.lemmas()], columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
              .drop_duplicates())
```

Here's how you can use it:

```
>>> genres = ['protest', 'riot', 'conflict']
>>> df = process_genres(genres)
>>> df
        Col1                   Col2
0    protest                protest
1    protest           protestation
...
11      riot                   riot
12      riot        public_violence
13      riot                rioting
...
34  conflict               conflict
35  conflict               struggle
36  conflict                 battle
...
53  conflict             contravene
```

Answer (score 0):

Same logic that you have coded,  but use list comprehensions to build `pandas` constructor compatible structure

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
import pandas as pd

# same logic as question,  just use list comprehesions to process words and synonyms
# to build DF compatible construction list
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"col1":word, 
     # use set to take unique values
     "col2":{l.name() 
                  for syn in wordnet.synsets(word)
                  for l in syn.lemmas() 
            }
    }
    for word in ['protest','riot','conflict']
]).explode("col2") # expand embedded list of synonyms

# filter out word as a synonym of itself
df.loc[df.col1!=df.col2].head(10)
```

|  | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | protest | resist |
| 0 | protest | protestation |
| 0 | protest | objection |
| 0 | protest | dissent |
| 1 | riot | public_violence |
| 1 | riot | howler |
| 1 | riot | drunken_revelry |
| 1 | riot | orgy |
| 1 | riot | belly_laugh |
| 1 | riot | scream |